# C#, Trouble with RemoveAll removing only specific indexes

Tags: c#, lambda, predicate

I'm having some issues with my code and setting up a predicate statement.  C# is not the primary language I learned to code with, and lambda statements are not something I am entirely familiar with.

This is an example of what I need to run, the code works as intended, but it has been deemed that it would be preferred to use the RemoveAll method over the foreach->while->if loop that I have.

For posterity's sake, here is the "working" function as it is. Currently being used as a wrapper function.

```
private void UnassignHelper(ThingDbFactory thingFactory,     
IEnumerable<Thing> assignedThings, string groupName)
{
    foreach(var thing in assignedThings)
        while(thing.ThingGroups.Contains(groupName))
        {
            if(thing.ThingGroups.Remove(groupName))
            {
                thingFactory.Save(thing);
            }
        }
}
```

In it's ugly entirely, this code pyramid does exactly what it is supposed to.  What has been asked is that I use RemoveAll() instead, but the problem is that my currently tested methods are not working.

`item.ItemGroups.RemoveAll(i => item.ItemGroups.Contains(itemGroupName));`

Has been tested,  that method has removed ALL of my ItemGroup assignments instead of just the ItemGroup assignments I need removed.

`item.ItemGroups.RemoveAll(i => item.ItemGroups == itemGroupName);`

is not valid, because I can't compare System.Collections.Generic.List and string.

`item.ItemGroups.RemoveAll(i => item.ItemGroups.Equals(itemGroupName));`

is valid code, but it doesn't do anything when running the code.

For further documentation what I am trying to compare is not the key, but the value `itemGroupName`, here is the structure of the item in concerns to the issue.

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "Name" : "Banana",
    "ItemGroups" : [
        "Not the group to remove",
        "The duplicated group to remove",
        "The duplicated group to remove",
        "The duplicated group to remove"
    ],
}
```

Where, in debugging through Visual Studio, the actual item will be reflected as such (using a mock of what the structure looks like when placing a watch on it):

```
item
----ItemGroups
--------[0]["not the group to remove"]
--------[1]["the duplicate group to remove"]
--------[2]["the duplicate group to remove"]
--------[3]["the duplicate group to remove"]
```

Any suggestions of how to better structure the code without using the foreach->while->if loop would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Predicates in `RemoveAll` should determine, if a particular item should be removed. That's why you have the item as the input parameter `i` in your lambda.

This should do the job you are looking for:

```
item.ItemGroups.RemoveAll(i => i == groupName);
```

`i` is the input, in this case each item from the `ItemGroups` list. The lambda should return true if that item should be removed. `i == groupName` checks if the input matches the groupName you are looking for.

Comment: Omg, I could kiss you right now. This did exactly what I needed.